# How do you clone a cheerio object

Tags: cheerio

I've got a cheerio object:

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<span class="layer-chunk"></span>')
```

This is a simple example it is far more complex.

I need to clone it so that I can do different things with it without actually effecting it.

This is what I've got so far:

```
const clone = $ => {
  const strHtml = $('body').html()
  return cheerio.load(strHtml)
}
const myClone = clone($)
```

But I am sure this is not a cheap op. There is a [clone method in the docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#clone) but I cannot get it to work. I've tried this:

```
const myClone = $.root().clone()
```

But no cigar. Anyone know best practice for cloning a cheerio object? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just do:

```
cheerio.load($.html())
```

Comment: thats an improvement thanks - will accept if noone answers with how to use clone()

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/e2f8436170e56190beb0dbbd284065624ca4d329/Readme.md#clone) all you need to do is

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<div id="fruits">This is <em>content</em>.</div>')
const moreFruit = $('#fruits').clone()
```

or you can check `cloneDom` on the this [link](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/e2f8436170e56190beb0dbbd284065624ca4d329/lib/utils.js#L63)

> Create a deep copy of the given DOM structure by first rendering it to
> a  * string and then parsing the resultant markup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to actually use the clone you have to do it like this:

```
cheerio('.layer-chunk', clone).text('something')
                        ^^^^^
```